# How can I set a password for Elasticsearch 2.3.0 running in Docker?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I am trying to modify an existing installation of Elasticsearch (I believe it's version 2.3.0) running on Docker. Most of the information I'm finding online is for newer versions of Elasticsearch, but I'm hoping to avoid having to update the whole thing.

I need to restrict access to Elasticsearch for security reasons. I'm trying to set a password, but so far I haven't had any luck. Most of the tutorials I've found (apart from being about later version of Elasticsearch) talk about using X-Pack, but I don't think this is installed in the docker container. Is it necessary to install X-Pack, or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

2.3 is super old, there was no security back then and was only added in 5.6

you will need to use something like nginx to manage, or ideally, upgrade to a supported version. Security is free these days as well

Comment: I see. Thank you, I will investigate those options.